# Can I enter a Schengen country (France) during the last two days of validity of my tourist visa?

Tags: schengen, france, afghan-citizens

I have an Afghan passport.

If I remain in Europe during the last two days of a Schengen tourist visa, can I enter France?

Comment: What do you mean by "remain in Europe"?  From where are you planning to enter France?  How long do you want to stay in France?

Comment: A visa gives you free access to the entirety of the Schengen area up until the midnight of the last date of your visa. You could enter France 8pm on the last day of your visa to depart from Paris and it still would be OK. Not quite sure what are you asking. Theoretically you could even be given a two days visa!

Answer (score 1):

In Europe (at least in Schengen zone) border control does not exist. But there is a chance that a border guard will check you (randomly) or stop your car if you go by car. If you plan to go to France by aeroplane, then probably in the airport Security can stop you (but I am not sure) and ask your plans. But flights within Schengen zone do not have border control, only passport control.